# Typescript type safe function params

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to make the `filterValue` param (which depends on the type of the `GitHubRepositoryFilter` key) type safe?

```js
export type GitHubRepositoryFilter = {
  withName?: string;
  withWorkflowRuns?: boolean;
};

export const repositoryFilters: Record<
  keyof GitHubRepositoryFilter,
  (repository: GitHubRepository, filterValue: any) => boolean
> = {
  withWorkflowRuns: ({ hasWorkFLows }, filterValue) => hasWorkFLows === filterValue,
  withName: ({ name }, filterValue) => name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.toLowerCase()),
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
export type GitHubRepositoryFilter = {
  withName?: string;
  withWorkflowRuns?: boolean;
};

type GitHubRepositoryFilters = {
  [K in keyof GitHubRepositoryFilter]: (
    repository: GitHubRepository,
    filterValue: GitHubRepositoryFilter[K]
  ) => boolean
};

export const repositoryFilters: GitHubRepositoryFilters = {
  withWorkflowRuns: ({ hasWorkFlows }, filterValue)
    => hasWorkFlows === filterValue,
  withName: ({ name }, filterValue)
    => name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue?.toLowerCase()),
};
```

Comment: I add a `NonNullable<GitHubRepositoryFilter[K]>`, now it's perfect.

Comment: I get still an error when I try to use it. Here is an example
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-z6e1qx?file=/index.ts:932-933